# Single .htaccess file that allows vanity URLs and Sessions

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to create an .htaccess file that does two things. Firstly, I need it to allow me to have vanity URLs that pass to a page called profile.php. Secondly, I want to be able to have sessions remain consistent regardless of whether the user types www. or not in the browser. I have both of these capabilities working in two separate .htaccess scripts. I need a single .htaccess file that will allow me to do both of these things.

This allows me to do the vanity url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/profile.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

This allows me to have a single set of sessions without worrying about www.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Any help combining these into a single .htaccess file would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this wouldn't be better on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to redirect before you route. But your route needs to have the `http://www.website.com` removed otherwise there will be an implicit redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Quick question though, this doesn't seem to work if the user puts just http://website.com. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, http://website.com works in a normal browser. However in my iOS app there are instances where I point to the website without www and it gets messed up. Any ideas on how to address?

Comment: THanks Jon, are you referring to the app itself or to the .htaccess code?

Comment: @user2492064 the htaccess code: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]`

Comment: You are completely awesome. Thank you!